# How to duplicate records with triggers?

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "DUPLICATE_FOO" AFTER INSERT ON "FOO" FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    insert into remote_foo values(:new); -- can I do this?
EXCEPTION
    -- TODO log somewhere
END;
```

Is there an elegant way to create a trigger that basically duplicates a record from one table to another?

I would like to avoid having to specify the fields of the table since it will mean that the trigger would have to be updated in case there are changes in the schema (the remote scheme would be updated of course). I have like a dozen of tables more.

All the [examples](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_insert.php) I have found always specify the fields in the insert (`:new.fieldX`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *keyword* here is NOT to specify column names, right? In my opinion, you should because that's the only way you can control it.

> the remote scheme would be updated **of course**

is kind of *dangerous*. WHAT IF it doesn't happen? "Of course" works until it does not work.

---

Sample tables (both are empty):

```
SQL> create table foo (id number, name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create table remote_foo as select * From foo where 1 = 2;

Table created.
```

If you use a trigger which is an autonomous transaction, then it won't see `:new` pseudorecord (as this is an *autonomous* transaction; right?); to this trigger, `select * from foo where id = :new.id;` won't return anything and `remote_foo` remains empty:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_ai_foo
  2    after insert on foo
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  6  begin
  7    insert into remote_foo select * from foo where id = :new.id;
  8    commit;
  9  end;
 10  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into foo (id, name) values (1, 'Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from foo;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Littlefoot

SQL> select * from remote_foo;           --> it remained empty

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Note that - if you specified columns - it would work (but that's not what you wanted):

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_ai_foo
  2    after insert on foo
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  6  begin
  7    insert into remote_foo (id, name) values (:new.id, :new.name);
  8    commit;
  9  end;
 10  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into foo (id, name) values (2, 'Bigfoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from foo;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         2 Bigfoot

SQL> select * from remote_foo;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         2 Bigfoot

SQL>
```

---

So, what to do? Switch to a statement-level trigger (instead of a row-level): it doesn't have to be autonomous, but has to have *something* that will prevent duplicates to be inserted - for example, a `NOT EXISTS` clause:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_ai_foo
  2    after insert on foo
  3  begin
  4    insert into remote_foo
  5      select * from foo a
  6      where not exists (select null from remote_foo b
  7                        where b.id = a.id);
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into foo (id, name) values (1, 'Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into foo (id, name)
  2    select 2, 'Bigfoot'   from dual union all
  3    select 3, 'anat0lius' from dual;

2 rows created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from foo;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         2 Bigfoot
         3 anat0lius
         1 Littlefoot

SQL> select * from remote_foo;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Littlefoot
         3 anat0lius
         2 Bigfoot

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I give u more context: The issue is that the DB has grown a lot and some external queries (not part of the main application) that are being performed take too much time (even though the query uses indexes, but not the one for which the DB is partitioned). And the solution is to have a duplicate of the schema but only with data of the last week, so the queries perform ok. And we think by adding triggers and a scheduled job to clean periodically will do it.

Comment: The main application is optimized for inserts, and we want to test this solution to see if the impact is not significant, that's why I want to be an autonomous tx. Using selects, as you show in the examples, will not be good for us I think. You also mention that with autonomous tx I won't be able to access the :new pseudorecord, then what alternatives do I have?

Comment: From my point of view, I'd create a stored procedure which would copy data (you mentioned - the last week's data) into another tables and then **schedule** it to run ... well, periodically. Another option is to create **materialized view** which contains data you're interested in, and which refreshes whenever you find appropriate. Perhaps ON COMMIT would be OK, regarding the fact that you tried to do that using a database trigger (which fires immediately after insert).

Comment: I have just tested the trigger and I succeeded by referencing `:new.myField`. I didn't understand what you mean when you said that is incompatible with autonomous transaction.

Comment: In the end, I saw is not possible, indeed. Triggers that are autonomous transactions are not possible to be called from distributed transactions, which is what our application uses. So we will change the approach.